# How do I run a function every second

Tags: r

I want to run a function that takes less than one second to execute. I want to run it in a loop every second. I do not want to wait one second between running the function like `Sys.sleep` would do.

```
while(TRUE){
  # my function that takes less than a second to run
  Sys.sleep(runif(1, min=0, max=.8))  

  # wait for the remaining time until the next execution...
  # something here
}
```

I could record a `starttime <- Sys.time()` and do a comparison every iteration through the loop, something like this...

```
starttime <- Sys.time()
while(TRUE){
  if(abs(as.numeric(Sys.time() - starttime) %% 1) < .001){
    # my function that takes less than a second to run
    Sys.sleep(runif(1, min=0, max=.8))  
    print(paste("it ran", Sys.time()))
  }
}
```

But my function never seems to be executed.

I know python has a package to do this sort of thing. Does R also have one that I don't know about? Thanks.

Comment: I guess the problem is that there is a 1/1000 chance of being at the right time in each iteration. It should still run eventually, though I can't get it to...

Comment: It appears like you want a cron job within R. Depending on the specifics, it might be better to do this with the usual command line tools.

Comment: Per @Roland's comment, let's make sure we don't have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: @JasonAizkalns always a good point, but to be fair a lot of times the problem you're trying to solve is too broad/vague for this site and you do need to ask about a specific solution

Answer (score 15):

You can keep track of the time with `system.time`

```
while(TRUE)
{
    s = system.time(Sys.sleep(runif(1, min = 0, max = 0.8)))
    Sys.sleep(1 - s[3]) #basically sleep for whatever is left of the second
}
```

You can also use `proc.time` directly (which system.time calls), which for some reasons got better results for me:

```
> system.time(
  for(i in 1:10)
  {
    p1 = proc.time()
    Sys.sleep(runif(1, min = 0, max = 0.8))
    p2 = proc.time() - p1
    Sys.sleep(1 - p2[3]) #basically sleep for whatever is left of the second
  })
   user  system elapsed 
   0.00    0.00   10.02
```

Comment: Any sort of overhead done by `system.time` or the `while` loop will throw this off, so it will be slightly more than a second. You could do the work to compensate for that if you'd like.

Answer (score 12):

Here are some alternatives.  These do *not* block.  That is you can still use the console to run other code while they are running.

**1) tcltk** Try `after` in the tcltk package:

```
library(tcltk)

run <- function () { 
  .id <<- tcl("after", 1000, run) # after 1000 ms execute run() again
  cat(as.character(.id), "\n")    # replace with your code
}

run()
```

Running this on a fresh R session gives:

```
after#0 
after#1 
after#2 
after#3 
after#4 
after#5 
after#6 
after#7 
...etc...
```

To stop it `tcl("after", "cancel", .id)` .

**2) tcltk2** Another possibility is `tclTaskSchedule` in the tcltk2 package:

```
library(tcltk2)

test <- function() cat("Hello\n")  # replace with your function
tclTaskSchedule(1000, test(), id = "test", redo = TRUE)
```

Stop it with:

```
tclTaskDelete("test")
```

or `redo=` can specify the number of times it should run.

Answer (score 3):

Another **non-blocking** alternative worth mentioning is provided by library([later](https://github.com/r-lib/later)), via using `later()` recursive:

```
print_time = function(interval = 10) {
  timestamp()
  later::later(print_time, interval)
}

print_time()
```

The example is taken from [here](https://yihui.name/en/2017/10/later-recursion/).

Answer (score 2):

The `shiny` package has a function `invalidateLater()`  which can be use to trigger functions. Have a look at http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/timer.html

Answer (score 1):

Although its very late.

As an alternative we can use recursion. I don't know if its the solution you are looking for. But it executes function at regular interval.

```
ssc <-  function(){
x <- rnorm(30,20,2)
print(hist(x))
 Sys.sleep(4)

 ssc()

 }
ssc()
```

Comment: This will only work for a limited number of times. Please read [this](https://yihui.name/en/2017/10/later-recursion/): `R has a global option 'expressions' that defaults to 5000, which means it can only evaluate 5000 nested expressions by default. If there isn’t an exit in the recursion, it will blow up at some point [...]`