# R : Changing values of variables after certain time

Tags: r, function, graph

the question I am trying to ask is how to I change one of the values of my variables (noted as LO$M in my list) after I pass a certain time.

The thing I am trying to achieve is that after 20,000 seconds passing I would like to change my value of Lac to the value of Lac at time 20,0000 +10,000

So at t = 20,000, Lac = Lac + 10,000

The issue I am having with my code is that within my if command I have if tt>= 20000, but this leads to the issue that every value of Lac after 20,000 being increased by 10,000 when what i want is that the FIRST value after 20,000 be increased by 10,000.

Basically, after 20,000 of my experiment passing I am trying to inject 10,000 more Lac into the experiment.

My code is given below:

```
LO = list()
LO$M = c(i = 1, ri = 0, I = 50, Lac = 20, ILac = 0, o = 1, Io = 0, RNAP = 100, RNAPo = 0, r = 0, z = 0)
LO$Pre = matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
                  0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
                  0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
                  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1), ncol=11, byrow=TRUE)
LO$Post = matrix(c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), ncol=11, byrow=TRUE)
LO$h = function(x,t,th=c(0.02,0.1,0.005,0.1,1,0.01,0.1,0.01,0.03,0.1,1e-05,0.01,0.002,0.01,0.001))
{
  with(as.list(c(x, th)), {
    return(c(th[1]*i, th[2]*ri, th[3]*I*Lac, th[4]*ILac, th[5]*I*o, th[6]*Io, th[7]*o*RNAP,
             th[8]*RNAPo, th[9]*RNAPo, th[10]*r, th[11]*Lac*z, th[12]*ri, th[13]*I, 
             th[13]*ILac, th[14]*r, th[15]*z))
  })
}

gillespie1 = function (N, n, ...) 
{
  tt = 0
  x = N$M
  S = t(N$Post - N$Pre)
  u = nrow(S)
  v = ncol(S)
  tvec = vector("numeric", n)
  xmat = matrix(ncol = u, nrow = n + 1)
  xmat[1, ] = x
  for (i in 1:n) {
    h = N$h(x, tt, ...)
    tt = tt + rexp(1, sum(h))
    j = sample(v, 1, prob = h)
    x = x + S[, j]
    tvec[i] = tt
    xmat[i + 1, ] = x
    if( tt >=20000){
      x[4] = x[4] +10000
    }
  }
  return(list(t = tvec, x = xmat))
}

newout = gillespie1(LO,200000)
matplot(newout$x[,4], type="l", lwd=0.25, col="grey")
```

I don't have a high enough reputation to attach images, but it should look something like this:
https://gyazo.com/0ffd940a22df23b2ccfdf4a17e85dca8

Sorry if this isn't clear. Thanks

Comment: You can execute your function every N second. Some examples in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36086599/how-do-i-run-a-function-every-second

Comment: Hi, I have a second function where I execute my function every second for 50,000 seconds (that's where I got the graph from), but for this circumstance I need the function to have random time intervals for execution. Do you have any ideas

Answer (score 0):

In this example, you have the function `myTask()`. When you call `execMyTask()`, you will execute `myTask()`once, and after that, you will execute it at random intervals between 1 to max_wait milliseconds. When you get tired, you can kill the task with `tclTaskDelete()`.

```
library(tcltk2)

myTask <- function() cat("some task!\n")

id = "execMyTask"

execMyTask <- function(max_wait = 3000) {
  id <- toString(match.call()[[1]])
  myTask()
  wait = sample(1:max_wait, 1)
  cat("Waiting", wait, "miliseconds\n")  # replace with your function

  if (is.null(tclTaskGet(id))) {
    tclTaskSchedule(wait=wait, execMyTask(), id=id, redo = TRUE)
  } else {
    tclTaskChange(wait=wait, execMyTask(), id=id, redo = TRUE)
  }

}

execMyTask()
tclTaskDelete(id)
```

So far, there is a little problem with this approach, because we can not supply arguments to the function *fun* in `tclTaskChange()`.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I already have the gillespie1 function, which repeats n times and each time i repeat the time increases by a random time given by exponential distribution. I, however, want to find the first value of t which is greater than or equal to 20,000