# Update Dataframe for every 5 Seconds in R

Tags: r

I need to update my dataframe for every 5 seconds, upon searching I found out how to run a function for every 5 seconds, but couldn't able to figure out how to update a dataframe, like a repeat `rbind()` for every 5 seconds.

Below is my attempted R-Script

```
library(tcltk2)

 mydata <- data.frame()
 string_val <- "Hello World"

 fupdate <- function(){
        rbind(mydata , string_val)
       }

 tclTaskSchedule(5000, fupdate(), id = "fupdate", redo = TRUE)
```

I referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36086599/how-do-i-run-a-function-every-second) for re-running the functions.

Comment: Can you please specify your question and expected output? Do you get any error messages, if yes, include them in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new to the `tcltk2` package, but I believe you could do the following:

```
library(tcltk2)

mydata <- data.frame()
string_val <- data.frame(text ="Hello World")

fupdate <- function(){
  if (nrow(mydata)==0)
    mydata <<- string_val
  else
    mydata <<- rbind(mydata , string_val)
}

tclTaskSchedule(1000, fupdate(), id = "fupdate", redo = 10)
tclTaskRun('fupdate')
```

Note that to rbind, you need to have two `data.frames`, and not one `data.frame` and a `string`, so I modified your `string_val` variable. To continuously update `mydata`, we can use the `<<-` operator, which writes back to the parent environment.

Hope this helps!